# Ledge Trace Unreal engine 5

Tags: c++, logic, game-development, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I am trying to make a ledge climb system in Unreal engine 5. I have applied some capsule traces in order to detect the ledges, however I want the character to not move in the direction where the ledge is not detected by the capsule trace but move in the other direction where ledge is present. How can I achieve that?[Here is the screenshot, As per this Image I want the character to move in the Right direction and not in the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw0pL.jpg)

I have tried putting the stop movement node if the ledge is not traced but it is stopping the movement completely.

Comment: I recommend asking in the Unreal forums, where there's a lot more people than here that know a lot about Unreal.